# Maya FBX and TGA to Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, import

I have some models that were created in Maya 2016/2017 and exported into FBX format with .tga files. I'm using Blender 2.8 and can't figure out how to display the textures correctly.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jerry. You can try: *File > External Data > Find Missing Files*.